# Resize Windows 10 notification area

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

For a long time, the windows notification area (aka, system tray) would stack icons 3 high, thus conserving real estate on the task bar. (Below in an example in XP).

[image]

I just upgraded from Windows 7 to windows 10 and now my system tray icons look like:

[image]

All icons are in a single row, which causes my taskbar to be truncated.  Is there any way to get back the more intelligent configuration of previous windows versions?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but you can clear up space by turning off "Always show all icons in the notification area" in Settings.

Comment: @Phlamajam, Already did that, those are the ones I like to see.